# Redux store - Database - how to propagate changes

Tags: redux, store, propagation

In my angular4 app I have 2 lists:
"list of my friends" and "list of xys friends"

I added both lists to the store, since I display them in different components and I want all my different components to realize changes on my lists instantly.

If one friend now changes its "name" i have the problem that i have to update the store at 2 points. In "list of my friends" and "list of xys friends". This feels wrong and confusing and hard to keep track of.

Another way would be to update the "name" in the database first and then re-request a new version of "list of my friends" and "list of xys friends".

But this takes a lot of time, especially once i have more lists.

So what is the professional approach to this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the exact reason why it's recommended to keep your data stores (especially Redux stores) flat. Usually, there should be minimal amount of nesting, and entities should reference each other by their ids.

It's better explained with an example. Currently, your data probably looks like this:

```
{
    allUsers: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Foo',
            friends: [
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: 'Bar',
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    name: 'Baz'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Bar',
            friends: [
                {
                    id: 3,
                    name: 'Baz'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Baz',
            friends: []
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, there is a lot of nesting and duplication. If any user changes their name, propagating this change through the whole store will be difficult, especially in more complex cases. However, if we flatten this structure, it becomes much nicer:

```
{
    users: {
        1: {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Foo',
            friends: [2, 3]
        },
        2: {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Bar',
            friends: [3]
        },
        3: {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Baz',
            frineds: []
        }
    },

    allUsers: [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Each entity is stored in one specific place. Other entities cannot include its data, but only reference it by id, so there is no need to synchronize the changes. This approach prevents a lot of problems with data integrity (including yours) and minimizes the memory footprint of the application.

As for querying such store, you can write functions that transform this data into shapes more convenient for reading, with an important assumption that their results will be read-only. In Redux, such functions are usually called *selectors*.